# Laurent Series Region

Tags: laurent-series

So, I'm trying to find the regions in which the function may be represented as a Laurent series (expanded about the origin).  Then I want to find those expansions:

$$f(z)=(z^2+1)^{-1/2}$$

Now, since there's a singularity at $-i \space \space and \space \space i$, the regions must be 0<|z|<1 and 1<|z|< infinity.  Well, I'm lost as to how the laurent series can be calculated.  If we expand about a point that isn't the singularity, is that expansion not just the taylor series?  In that case, we would form a binomial series, but I believe that only converges for 0<|z|<1.  How do we obtain the expansion for 1<|z|< infinity?

Comment: Why is it not analytic?  Could you please explain further?

Comment: Just an FYI: This response to my question is incorrect.  $f$ may be analytic for |z| > 1 if you choose a branch connecting i and -i (if you go around both singularities, then you end up at the same value.  It's only when you go around one pole that another value is generated).  So, you can have a Taylor series at |z|<1 and a Laurent series at |z|>1.  It depends on how you define your branch cut.

Comment: You are correct, of course. If $|z|>1$ then $f(z) = {1 \over z} (1+{1 \over z^2})^{-{1 \over 2}}$ which you can expand using the binomial series expansion. (I was incorrectly thinking of $\log$ in my earlier responses.)

Comment: Exactly, that's what I'm doing.  I just wanted to share the information here :)